# How to migrate AFC theme made from scratch to a Elementor theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

i have a question about how migrate the AFC from a theme made from scratch to a theme make with Elementor or other builders.

When i say from scratch i mean a theme made in the classic way without any builder.

Thank you!

None yet